# How do I refer between different APIs in SwaggerHub?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swaggerhub

I am working with SwaggerHub and OpenAPI 3.0.0. I have two APIs in SwaggerHub.

The first has got following access link:
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/myapipath/1.0.0 and contains a definition named `components/schemas/ApiOffer`.

In the second API, I want the property `offer` to be a `$ref` to that definition. I use:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Offerers:
      type: object
      required:
        - offererId
        - overview
      properties:
        offererId:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OfferersId'
        overview:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OfferersOverview'
        offer:
          $ref: 'https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/myapipath/1.0.0#/components/schemas/ApiOffer'
```

but get the following error:

> "Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer:
>   /components/schemas/ApiOffer does not exist in document"

even though the `/components/schemas/ApiOffer` definition exists.

How do I correct my reference so that it points to the other API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

References to SwaggerHub definitions must use the hostname `API.swaggerhub.com` instead of `APP.swaggerhub.com`.